# Simple PHP regex replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

Given the following text:

```
1. Place pastry on microwave safe plate.2. Heat on high for 3 seconds.3. Cool briefly before handling.
```

I am wanting to replace all occurrences of a dot followed by a number (any number) followed by a dot.

Eg.

```
.2. or .15.
```

and replace it with

```
.<BR>number.
```

For the preg_replace pattern, I am currently using:

```
$pattern = "/^(\.[0-9]\.)/";
$replacement = "";

$text=  preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

How do I , using preg_replace , replace the text so that it puts a 
 between the first dot and the number?

Comment: Remove `^` and try again `"/\.[0-9]+\./"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one. Here we are using `preg_replace`.

> **Search:** `/\.(\d+)\./` Added `+` for capturing more than one digit and changed capturing group for only digits.
>
> **Replace:** `.<BR>$1.` `$1` will contain digits captured in search expression.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/860397)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string = "1. Place pastry on microwave safe plate.2. Heat on high for 3 seconds.3. Cool briefly before handling.";
echo preg_replace("/\.(\d+)\./", ".<BR>$1.", $string);
```

Comment: demo link broken

Comment: @Jason Though that above code is working fine but you can test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) by removing `ini_set()` because it is disabled for security reasons on this website. The time I answered this question eval.in was working and now its not. Anyways Happy coding @Jason :)

Answer (score 1):

This will add the number and new line.

See demo here. https://regex101.com/r/ktd7TW/1

```
$re = '/\.(\d+)\./'; //I use () to capture the number and use it in the replace as $1 
$str = '1. Place pastry on microwave safe plate.2. Heat on high for 3 seconds.3. Cool briefly before handling.';
$subst = '.<br>$1.'; // $1 is the number captured in pattern

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '1. Place pastry on microwave safe plate.2. Heat on high for 3 seconds.3. Cool briefly before handling.';
$pattern = "/(?<=\.)(?=\d+\.)/";
$replacement = "<br>";
$text=  preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
echo $text;
```

**Output:**

```
1. Place pastry on microwave safe plate.<br>2. Heat on high for 3 seconds.<br>3. Cool briefly before handling.
```

**Explanation:**

```
/               : regex delimiter
    (?<=\.)     : lookbehind, make sure we have a dot before
    (?=\d+\.)   : lookahead, make sure we have digits and a dot after
/               : regex delimiter
```